# Heroku: Slug size is way bigger than local because of .apt file?

Tags: python, heroku

I deployed my first python + flask webapp a while ago using heroku and always got the warning
`Your slug size (365MB) exceeds our soft limit (300MB)`. Didnt mind too much until now when I looked up what exactly takes up how much space. Running bash to inspect the slug I get the following:

```
1.1G    /app
649MB   /app/.heroku
364M    /app/.apt
28M     /app/Lib
12M     /app/.chromedriver
2.0M    /app/Scripts
32K     /app/.procfile.d
20K     /app/__pycache__
16K     /app/main.py
4.0K    /app/hashtable.py
4.0K    /app/Procfile
4.0K    /app/requirements.txt
4.0K    /app/.locales
```

This doesnt look exactly like what I have locally. I suppose the `.heroku` folder was added  by heroku but the `.apt` too since that one is not on my local machine. If I look into it with `cd` and `ls` it very much looks like things that heroku needs so Im a bit careful to delete it

Im just confused because I never saw `.apt` on other projects and I feel like Im doing something wrong when all of my files are around 33MB and I have no idea where the other 330MB come from. Cant imagine that heroku puts 300MB of must needed files into the slug to run the web application

Does anyone have an explanation?
The buildpacks I use are:

```
heroku/python
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale.git
```

Edit:

If I type `heroku run bash` I see exactly the files that I see locally, without `.apt`. What I posted above is whats shown when I type `du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr`, which is a command suggested by heroku to see the current directory sorted by filesize

Since I also dont see the `.apt` file locally Im not sure how to use `.slugignore`. But in those files are also no dependencies or packages so Im pretty sure those are things needed by heroku?

Comment: did you resolve it by now? Having the same issue. @jfordummies

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Heroku CLI and the APT library are installed in your project folder, which should not be the case (these commands/libs are going to be used by other projects too).

I would remove and re-install them in a different (tools folder?) location.

Another option is to ignore these files using `.slugignore`, as they are not needed to run your Flask application, see Heroku [Slug Compiler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore) documentation.

Comment: I am not sure how to check the location of the APT Library but the location of heroku on my machine is not in the folder but in /program files and in the folder that I push into the repository there is also neither heroku CLI or APT Library so Im not sure how to put them into a .slugignore folder.

If I type heroku run bash I also see exactly the files that I see locally. What I posted above is whats shown when I type "du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr", which is a command suggested by heroku

Comment: the `.slugignore` works like `.gitignore`, just add the name of files and folders to ignore